# Parsing custom YAML tags with SnakeYAML/Scala

Tags: java, scala, parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

So I have a YAML that looks like this:

```yaml
--- !BigTag1
attribute_1: value1
attribute_2:
  - !SmallTag2
    sub_attribute_21:
      - sub_value_211
      - sub_value_212
    sub_attribute_22: sub_value_221
  - !SmallTag2
    sub_attribute_21:
      - sub_value_213
      - sub_value_214
    sub_attribute_22: sub_value_222
  - !SmallTag3
    sub_attribute_31: sub_value_311
    sub_attribute_32: sub_value_321
```

This YAML's structure is somewhat frozen because other systems read from it.

Now, I'm trying to read this YAML from Scala, i.e. something that would look like

```scala
  trait SmallTag
  case class SmallTag2(sub_attribute_21: Seq[String], sub_attribute_22: String) extends SmallTag
  case class SmallTag3(sub_attribute_31: String, sub_attribute_32: String) extends SmallTag

  case class BigTag1(attribute_1: String, attribute_2: Seq[SmallTag]) {
    override def toString: String = attribute_1
  }

  val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(BigTag1.getClass))
  val obj = yaml.load(data).asInstanceOf[BigTag1]
  println(obj)
```

Doing that, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=attribute_1 for JavaBean=BigTag1
 in 'string', line 2, column 5:
    --- !BigTag1
        ^
Unable to find property 'attribute_1' on class: YamlTest$BigTag1$
 in 'string', line 3, column 14:
    attribute_1: value1
```

Since SnakeYAML is a Java lib and I'm relatively new to Scala/Java and Scala in general, I'm not exactly sure how to handle this error. I'd expect I could extend the SnakeYAML's `Constructor` class but I'm not sure how to since it's Java based.

Could someone help me out on this ?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to implement the loaded object in Java since SnakeYAML uses reflection to discover properties which may cause problems with Scala classes (for all I know, it should generally work if you give the Scala properties `@BeanProperty` but I don't know Scala well enough to really trust that).  It is generally no problem to incorporate Java and Scala code, and you can simply follow the [SnakeYAML docs](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers) to implement loading in Java, and then call it in Scala.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm starting to wonder if SnakeYAML really is my best bet for YAML parsing if I have to start writing Java classes for it, do you know of any YAML lib that works well with YAML tags and is Scala exclusive ?

Comment: I do know little of Scala, what I can tell you is only that in order for some Java lib that uses reflection to work with Scala, you must ensure that the relevant Scala classes will be compiled to look the same as equivalent Java classes. You need a bit of knowledge about the compilation process to ensure that, which I don't possess. From a software engineering perspective, it seems to be the better option to use Java code here since you need not as much knowledge to maintain that. Jackson has [a scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala), might be worth a try.